# Piltz Divisor Problem

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, divisors-multiples

Let $\tau_k(n)$ count the number of ways of representing $n$ as the product of $k$ natural numbers. It is known that:

$$D_k(x) = \sum_{n \leq x} \tau_k(n) = xP_k(\log x) + O(x ^{1 - \frac{1}{k-1}}(\log x)^{k-2}), \; \forall k \geq 2$$

Where $P_k$ is a polynomial of degree $k-1$ with leading coefficient $\frac{1}{(k-1)!}$

I am asked to prove this. We may assume the base case as it is a well known result.

The assuming the result for all $l \leq k$:

$$D_k(x) = \sum_{mn \leq x} \tau_{k-1}(n) = \sum_{n\leq x}\lfloor{\frac{x}{n}}\rfloor\tau_{k-1}(n)$$

$$= \sum_{n \leq x}(\frac{x}{n} + O(1))\tau_{k-1}(n) = x\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\tau_{k-1}(n)}{n} + O(\sum_{n\leq x}\tau_{k-1}(n))$$

Using Abel's Summation formula, we may see that:

$$\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\tau_{k-1}(n)}{n} = P_k(\log x) + O(x^{\frac{-1}{k-1}}(\log x)^{k-3})$$

So:

$$D_k(x) = xP_k(\log x) + O(x^{1 - \frac{1}{k-1}}(\log x)^{k-3}) + O(\sum_{n \leq x}\tau_{k-1}(n))$$

Using the induction hypothesis:

$$O(\sum_{n \leq x}\tau_{k-1}(n)) = O(xP_{k-1}(\log x) + O(x^{1 - \frac{1}{k-1}}(\log x)^{k-3}))$$

$$= O(x(\log x)^{k-2}) + O(x^{1 - \frac{1}{k-1}}(\log x)^{k-3})) = O(x(\log x)^{k-2})$$

Thus we get:

$$D_k(x) = xP_k(\log x) + O(x^{1- \frac{1}{k-1}}(\log x)^{k-3}) + O(x(\log x)^{k-2})$$

$$=  xP_k(\log x)+O(x(\log x)^{k-2})$$

However, this error term is too large. How can I go about reducing it?

Comment: This question is not of research level (so it would be more suitable to ask at http://math.stackexchange.com/), but Greg Martin gave an excellent answer. In general, consulting the textbooks before asking a question might be useful. BTW I used Dirichlet's hyperbola method for a recent MO question here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/321839/an-interesting-sum-over-lattice-points-in-a-large-disk-centered-at-the-origin/321840#321840

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've discovered some of the primary motivation for the invention of the [Dirichlet hyperbola method](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~mdc/MATH31022/2011-12/notes/Notes5%202013%20Sums%20of%20Arithmetic%20functions%20level%204.pdf). Since $\tau_k = \tau_{k-1}*1$ (which you are already using), you can take advantage of the extra parameter ($U$ and $V$ in the linked document, instead of just $x$) to get a better error term—just as in the proof of the base case $k=2$.